# Programatically set LayoutMargins for UITableViewCell - iOS 7 alternative

Tags: uitableview, ios7

How do I set the margins (or insets, as they're called for iOS) in iOS 7 programatically?

In iOS 8, I set the margins using something like this:

```
cell.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 6.5,
                    bottom: BOTTOM_MARGIN_FOR_CELLS,
                    right: 6.5)
```

But I want the app to retain backwards compatibility with iOS7.

I need to set the margins programmatically, because there is a condition where the top cell has a different margin from the other cells.

Answer (score 1):

For **iOS7** use the following code

```
if ([myTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(separatorInset)]) {
    [myTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

For **iOS8** use the following code

```
if ([myTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(layoutMargins)]) {
    myTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

**Note:** Include both the code in your ViewController to support for both versions

Comment: The PO said that the top cell might have a different margins, whilst your solution affects the entire table view and all its cells in the same way (with no chance to configure the top one in a specific way).